# Put two input boxes and divs on same row

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following HTML:

```
        <div class="onerow">
            Site ID: <input type="text" name="siteId" id="siteId" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: siteId"/>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="onerow">
            <div id="select">
                <label for="state">View:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select id="state" data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="value: state" data-option-label="Select State">
                        <option value="2">All</option>
                        <option value="1">Active</option>
                        <option value="3">All except deleted</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="button" id="buttonsearch" value="Search" class="k-button" data-bind="events: {click: onSearchClick}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Or, in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j7ksuv9y/

I want to position both of those on the same row, one after the other. I've tried using `style="float: right"` but that only ends up placing the second input box to the far right of the screen, which is not what I want.

How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following css :

```
.onerow {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will make the element display inline but also as a block.

> Quote from
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)
>
> The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with
>   surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much
>   like a replaced element would)

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8o756Lwu/1/)

Comment: That worked. Thank you for the additional info. I'll be accepting your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

just update the CSS like below:

```
.onerow{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j7ksuv9y/4/)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways by which this can be achieved :-

1) One option as already mentioned above is by setting css to the class of the outer div as display:inline as mentioned

2)

```
<div class="onerow">
            <label class="lbl">Site ID: </label>
<input type="text" name="siteId" id="siteId" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: siteId"/>&nbsp;
<div class="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

is  by adding the below css :-

```
.lbl, .k-textbox
    {float:left}
```

In this clear both is mentioned so that it supports IE as well. This will work on all browsers and give the output as required.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `display:inline-block` on your row div's

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j7ksuv9y/5/)

```
<div class="onerow">
            Site ID: <input type="text" name="siteId" id="siteId" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: siteId"/>&nbsp;


                <label for="state">View:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select id="state" data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="value: state" data-option-label="Select State">
                        <option value="2">All</option>
                        <option value="1">Active</option>
                        <option value="3">All except deleted</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="button" id="buttonsearch" value="Search" class="k-button" data-bind="events: {click: onSearchClick}"/>

        </div>
```

Comment: Is this merely putting both the input box and the select box in a single `<div class="onerow">`? Oddly enough, I had tried that previously but had different results.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that you removed the div in which the select was located as well. I don't think I had tried it that way. Quite nice.

Comment: If you can use without div then why we use div so that i removed